# Selenium script to be used in QTP

Tags: selenium, qtp

There are 2 automaization tools in our project at this moment, one is Selenium, the other one is QTP. Now, we want to migrate the tests (develped in JAVA) on Selenium to QTP. So I would like to know if it is possible to do this thing cause for me, it's not in any situation...

Thanks in advance.

Allen

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to migrate scripts written in Selenium(Java) to QTP(vbscript)....

Answer (score 0):

from previous experience I would consider the opposite ;)

from QTP to selenium.

of course I know that if you paid for the license, there is little chance of going the other way... but... management management management... ;)

anyway you could do a kind of "porting" of the two languages but yeah it is not going to be faster than if you do it from scratch.